# Latin abbreviation "plagg."

Tags: abbreviations

used, e.g., [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=MJClpnoU-SUC&q=plagg) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=OUQ_AAAAcAAJ&q=plagg)

does it mean "pages"? how come?

checked all the entries beginning with "plag" on Logeion and the only one that could possibly fit is [plaga](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/plaga)

what's a good resource for expanding Latin abbreviations. I'm only aware of Cappelli's *Lexicon Abbreviaturarum* which is of limited use when working with printed texts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means *plagulae*, printing sheets. These are not pages (one sheet [contains several pages](https://www.lettertypen.de/hier-faellt-ein-druckbogen-in-die-auslage-des-ohz/)). 23 *plagulae* are one [bookbinder's alphabet](https://books.google.de/books?id=OnX2Zj1Vs0QC&pg=PA510&lpg=PA510&dq=alphabet#v=onepage&q=alphabet&f=false) (as the sheets are labelled with the letters A–Z, no J, V, W). The examples you found are book descriptions, so I **suspect** something like

> 4. Alph. IV. plagg. 13

means:

> A book made from [quarto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarto) sheets (4 pages on both sides of each sheet = 8 pages per sheet), 4 × 23 + 13 = 105 sheets, so 105 × 8 = 840 pages.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, each sheet is consecutively labelled with one letter of the alphabet (a "signature"), so 23 sheets is referred to as an alphabet. Right?

Comment: @ExpeditoBipes Yes, and the second alphabet is labelled Aa, Bb, …, the third Aaa, Bbb, … and so on. An example: First alphabet starts [here](https://archive.org/details/1545DieGanzeHeiligeSchriftLutherBibel/page/n23/mode/2up), second [here](https://archive.org/details/1545DieGanzeHeiligeSchriftLutherBibel/page/n391/mode/2up). The New Testament has its own alphabet (A), (B), … starting [here](https://archive.org/details/1545DieGanzeHeiligeSchriftLutherBibel/page/n1103/mode/2up). Newer books do not use this system and have simple Arabic numbering.

Comment: Thanks. It's right [here](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/plagula), kinda, but somehow I missed it. Seems to be a hapax legomenon in this sense in Roman literature. However, the modern meaning that you provided isn't given by any dictionary I've consulted. Hats off for figuring it out.